# How to return new object from function without making deep copying

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have function that return other object, and I need some clones of this object for working in some ways on it. The object is complex with array properties, and I want it arbitrary as I want without restriction to any data type.

But when I do it it's become the same reference on both objects and the same changes affect on both.

After investigating the issue I saw that if the object that returned from the function is in the global scope of JS so it will be the same reference, but if it's local on the function it will be new.

For example see the code. The x and y are same when I assign them from **func1**, but when I'm using **func2** each of them is other .

I am trying to save the need to make deep copying of object by using 3rd tools, or manually do it by my own service function.

Is there is a simple solution to this problem and I will glad to know what to learn for understand this.

Thanks.

```
let obj1 = {
    a:"Ay", 
    b: "Bi"
}

function func1(){

    return obj1;
}


let x = func1 ();
let y = func1();
console.log(x , y);
x.a = "new value1 ";
console.log(x , y);
//both x & y changed


function func2(){
    let obj2 = {
    a:"Ay", 
    b: "Bi"
}
    return obj2;
}


x = func2 ();
y = func2();
console.log(x , y);
x.a = "other value1 ";
console.log(x , y);
//only x have changed
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*without making deep copying*" - isn't that exactly what you want to do?

Comment: "*Is there is a simple solution?*" - you already found it: just move the object literal into the function so that it gets recreated on every call.

Comment: @Bergi I ment without doing it manually just use the function for that. And thank you and the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are passed by reference in Javascript you can use [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create the clones

```js
let obj1 = {
 a:"Ay", 
 b: "Bi"
}

function func1() {
 return {...obj1};
}


let x = func1 ();
let y = func1();
console.log(y);
x.a = "new value1 ";
console.log(x , y);


function func2(){
 return {
 a:"Ay", 
 b: "Bi"
}
}


x = func2 ();
y = func2();
console.log(x , y);
x.a = "other value1 ";
console.log(x , y);
```

There are other methods to create the copy of objects check below for the fastest
https://jsperf.com/deep-copy-vs-json-stringify-json-parse/5

Comment: Keep in mind that this will only make a shallow copy.

Comment: @Seblor yes I know, that's why added the link which has the methods to do the deep copy.